# How can I disable the Vim scroll-while-typing when I do a search?

Tags: linux, vim

I recently upgraded the OS on a server (runs a Debian based OS) and this newer version of vim seems to be ignoring `/etc/vim/vimrc`. The file `/etc/vim/vimrc.local` does not exist. I don't have a `.vimrc` in my home directory. Entering `:set noincsearch` does work, so wondering if anyone knows what's up (vimrc posted below just in case). Thanks!

[image]

```
runtime! debian.vim
if has("syntax")
  syntax on
endif
set ignorecase          " Do case insensitive matching
set smartcase           " Do smart case matching
set noincsearch         " Incremental search
set noautowrite         " Automatically save before commands like :next and :make
if filereadable("/etc/vim/vimrc.local")
  source /etc/vim/vimrc.local
endif
set bg=dark
set ts=3
set shiftwidth=3
set expandtab
set t_ti= t_te=
nnoremap <F3> "=strftime("%Y-%m-%d").' - '.$LOGNAME.' ('.$LC_SSH_USER.') - '<CR>P
inoremap <F3> <C-R>=strftime("%Y-%m-%d").' - '.$LOGNAME.' ('.$LC_SSH_USER.') - '<CR>
inoremap <F2> <C-R>'echo -e "\033[1;31;40m1RED2GREEN3YELLOW4BLUE5MAG6CYAN\033[0;0m"<CR>
let &titlestring = hostname() . "[vim(" . expand("%:t") . ")]"
if &term == "screen"
  set t_ts=^[k
  set t_fs=^[\
endif
if &term == "screen" || &term == "xterm"
  set title
endif
let hostname=system('echo -n $LOGNAME@$(/bin/hostname -s)')
set laststatus=2
set statusline+=%{hostname}\ %F\ %P\ %c:%l
hi statusline ctermbg=4 ctermfg=15 cterm=NONE
autocmd FileType yaml setlocal ts=2 sts=2 sw=2 expandtab
```

Comment: `Last set from /usr/share/vim/vim80/defaults.vim`.  Nice, thanks!  Just as @eckenrod mentioned as well (downvoted?).  Why this file would take precedence over site-wide prefs in `/etc/vim/` I do not know. I've nuked it and things seem sane again.. so far

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to glean some information from [this post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/318824/vim-cutpaste-not-working-in-stretch-debian-9). Your vim might be using default settings in `/usr/share/vim/vim80/defaults.vim`. Try changing the settings in that file (which included a `set incsearch` line for me), or try placing the contents of your `/etc/vim/vimrc` file into a new `~/.vimrc`.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to post. I removed `defaults.vim` and rely instead on my site-wide prefs in `/etc/vim/`

Comment: @ServerFault glad it helped!